# laravel eagerloading with function does not return relation but separateley works

Tags: laravel, relational-database, eager-loading

i have the following models

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Masters\System;

class UserActivationCode extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{

    public $table = "user_activation_codes";
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Model;
use Modules\Requests\Models\EmploymentLeaveType;
use App\Models\Masters\System\UserActivationCode;

class EmployeeEmployment extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {

    public $table = "employee_employments";

    public function employeeProfileScore() {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\EmployeeProfileScore', 'employee_id', 'employee_id');
    }
    public function test() {
        return $this->hasMany(UserActivationCode::class, 'employment_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

in tinker when i run the following commands

```
$emp = \App\Models\EmployeeEmployment::with('test')->whereIn('id', ["4228e839-5ce3-4798-acfd-68958fed3b82"])->first();
$emp->test;
```

the result is empty array

but when i run without with it returns data

```
$emp = \App\Models\EmployeeEmployment::whereIn('id', ["4228e839-5ce3-4798-acfd-68958fed3b82"])->first();
$emp->test;
```

i removed everything from model converted it into base state
in query i have the following query running i cant understand why employment_id in 0

```
[2024-01-24T11:08:27.192268+00:00] Query.INFO: select * from `employee_employments` where `id` in (?) {"Bindings":["4228e839-5ce3-4798-acfd-68958fed3b82"],"Time":2.65,"Origin":[]} []
```

[2024-01-24T11:08:27.197588+00:00] Query.INFO: select * from `user_activation_codes` where `user_activation_codes`.`employment_id` in (0) {"Bindings":[],"Time":1.29,"Origin":[]} []

Answer (score 0):

Check how your test relationship is being loaded. Is there perhaps a mismatch between the foreign keys and what is set in your database? Make sure that employment_id and id in the user_activation_codes table are of the same type in your database (both UUID if you are using UUIDs).

Comment: the employment_id table in user_activation_codes and id column in employee_employments table is of same type

Answer (score 0):

it seems the issue was a property of model,
You need to add protected $keyType = 'string'; to models with pk that is string.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30702